# Phonegap bug: "Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down."

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

why?
i have made an application ,i have added a  horizontal image gallery which moves from left to right and vice-versa on touch.i have slide it with using touchslider.js.but when i moves my page  up and down from the place where gallery is placed,,,,i suffer an error of---((("Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down in logcat."",.,..,,.))),,and my page does not move up and down,,except the other place from where gallery is not passing,.,.,.

The actual bug is that why my page is not moving up and down from ,from the place where gallery is passing..?

My page is moving up and down from remaining space left where gallery is not passing??
but it is not moving up and down from the place where gallery is using the space and the error is coming of("Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down"),,in the log cat.
how should i solve it????
suggest its urgent???